# Probability that the second and third card extracted are both aces?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, lotteries

I would like to know if the following reasoning is correct: the situation is the extraction without replacement of 3 cards out of 40, where there are 4 aces. I would say the cardinality of the sample space is $\frac {40!}{(40-3)!}$ because order matters here, and P(C2 and C3 are aces) = P(C2 is an ace) × P(C3 is an ace | C2 is an ace) = $\frac{4\cdot \binom {39}{1}}{40\cdot39\cdot38} \frac{3\cdot \binom {38}{1}}{40\cdot39\cdot38} $

Comment: Where are the $\binom{39}{1}$ and $\binom{38}{1}$ from?

Comment: You appear to be on the right track, however the P(C2 is an ace) and P(C3|C2) depend on whether C1 was an ace.  There are two different ways in which C2 and C3 will be an ace: (1) C1 was also an ace, or (2) C1 was not an ace.

Comment: For (1) N=36*4*3 = 432

Comment: For (2) N=4*3*2 = 24.  So the total number of ways of getting C2 and C3 as an ace = 432+24=456.  Then P(C2 and C3 = ace) = 456/(40*39*38).

Comment: @Andrew Gray You can just forget the first card. The probability that second and third are aces will not differ from the probability that the first and second are aces

Comment: @Andrew Still, it was another way for John's direct approach, thanks

Comment: @Elizabeth From a misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the event that the second card is an ace and let  $F$ denote the event that the third card is an ace.

Then:$$P (E\cap F)=P (E)P(F|E)=\frac4{40}\frac3{39}$$

Comment: Why is $P(E)=4/40$ given that $E $ is about the second card, i.e. isn't it implied that we know that a card has been drawn, and thus we should divide by $39$?

Comment: Though I know I'm wrong since your result equals $\frac {4\cdot3\cdot38}{40\cdot39\cdot38}$

Comment: Simply because there are 40 cards that can turn out to be the second card and this with equal probability. This is not changed by drawing a first card

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear you got it. Let this knowledge sink deep into you. It spares you from making things more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you need *exactly* two aces (second and third card only) then first pick the non-ace ($36$) then pick the two aces in order $(4\cdot 3)$.

If you need *at least* two aces (second and third cards definitely, but the first can be an ace also) then choose the second and third cards as aces $(4 \cdot 3)$ then choose the first card as anything else $(38)$.

Comment: Very easy once you see it... I had misunderstood something from my book but now I got this approach (that is not proceeding to use the multiplicative formula)

Comment: I realized after I wrote the answer that I didn't use your method at all. Do you *need* to answer with conditional probabilities?

Comment: No, not really. And for my method there's drhab's answer. However I'm trying to understand, in his notation, why we divide by $40$ in calculating $P(E)$, as I thought it was implied that a card has already been drawn

Answer (score -1):

You have got is just slightly wrong.  The probability that the second card is an ace will be $\frac3{40}$ because it is $\frac3{39}$ times the probability that the first card was not an ace, plus $\frac2{39}$ times the probability that the first card *was* an ace:
$$
\frac3{39}\frac{37}{40}+\frac2{39}\frac3{40} = \frac3{39}\frac{37}{40}+\frac2{39}\frac3{40} = \frac3{39}\frac{37}{40}+\frac3{39}\frac2{40} =
\frac3{39}\left(\frac{37}{40}+\frac2{40} \right)=\frac3{40}
$$
Then the probability that the third card is also an ace will be $\frac2{39}$ to the answer probability is $\frac1{260}$.

If you want to do it by counting cases, the number of success cases is 
$3$ (which A is in slot 2) times $2$ (which other A is in slot 3) times $388$ (which card is in slot $1$).
$$
\frac{3\cdot 2\cdot 38}{40\cdot 39 \cdot 38} = \frac1{260}$$

Comment: The probability that the second card is an ace, given that the first was not an ace, is 4/39 times the probability that the first card was not an ace, which is 36/40 (on the second draw there are 4 aces left out of 39 cards).  Likewise, the probability that the second card was an ace, given that the first was an ace, is 3/39 times 4/40.  The sum of these two cases = 1/10 (not 3/40).

Comment: Actually the first card can be ignored completely. There are 40 equiprobable candidates for the second card and 4 of them are aces. That gives probability  $\frac{4}{40}$

Comment: @Andrew Gray So you are saying that the probability of the second card being an Ace, in a deck of three Aces and 37 other cards, is $\frac{1}{10}$? Think about that. Note that the problem specifies a deck with only **3** Aces, not $4$.